# Carga inicial de slick

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo este carrusel con la libreria slick.js, el cual tiene una reproducción automática, lo que sucede es que en un principio no carga bien, no se que pueda ser, me toca pasar a la segunda pestaña para que se ajuste (adjunto imagen de como me carga).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.slideSpa').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        dots: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
.dateHeadquarters .servicesValue {
  border: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  border-radius: 0 22px 0 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #E3E3E3;
  line-height: 25px;
  min-height: 350px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.dateHeadquarters .nextSlider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dateHeadquarters .nextSliderLeft {
  right: -75px;
}

.dateHeadquarters .nextSliderRight {
  left: -15px;
}

.dateHeadquarters .forSaber {
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.dateHeadquarters .forSaber:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-image: url(../assets/icon/point.svg);
  top: 5%;
  left: -1%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="dateHeadquarters">
  <div class="row slideSpa">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="servicesValue">
        <h3>
          Masaje revitalizante
        </h3>
        <h4>
          ¿Qué incluye?
        </h4>
        <p>
          Masaje
          <br> Zona húmeda
        </p>
        <h4>
          Tarifas
        </h4>
        <p>
          Categoría A. $3.900
          <br> Categoría B. $4.000
          <br> Categoría C. $9.500
          <br> Categoría D. $10.900
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="servicesValue">
        <h3>
          Masaje revitalizante con alimentación
        </h3>
        <h4>
          ¿Qué incluye?
        </h4>
        <p>
          Masaje
          <br> Zona húmeda
          <br> Tabla de quesos
        </p>
        <h4>
          Tarifas
        </h4>
        <p>
          Categoría A. $3.900
          <br> Categoría B. $4.000
          <br> Categoría C. $9.500
          <br> Categoría D. $10.900
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="servicesValue">
        <h3>
          Masaje revitalizante
        </h3>
        <br>
        <h4>
          ¿Qué incluye?
        </h4>
        <p>
          Masaje
          <br> Zona húmeda
        </p>
        <br>
        <h4>
          Tarifas
        </h4>
        <p>
          Categoría A. $3.900
          <br> Categoría B. $4.000
          <br> Categoría C. $9.500
          <br> Categoría D. $10.900
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="servicesValue">
        <h3>
          Masaje revitalizante
        </h3>
        <br>
        <h4>
          ¿Qué incluye?
        </h4>
        <p>
          Masaje
          <br> Zona húmeda
        </p>
        <br>
        <h4>
          Tarifas
        </h4>
        <p>
          Categoría A. $3.900
          <br> Categoría B. $4.000
          <br> Categoría C. $9.500
          <br> Categoría D. $10.900
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tratastes de usar $(document).ready en vez de $(window).load?

Comment: Nada, de hecho intente hasta poniendo la función del JS directamente en el HTML pero sigue sin funcionar bien.

Comment: Bueno te dire que el codigo que colocaste cuando lo ejecuto sale bien a la primera, intentastes colocarle o setear un width a dateHeadquarters para probar?

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar vertical: false en tu código, así:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.slideSpa').slick({
    vertical:false,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        dots: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000
      }
    }]
  });
});
```